# In JQuery Mobile, select dialog is not centered and cut by the page width

Tags: jquery, select, mobile, dialog

I have a JQuery Mobile page. It has two selects elements side by side on the top.

When opening the page on a small and narrow screen such as iphone, and clicking on the select, the dialog shows up too much to the side (not centered) and the text is cut off.

[Example here.](https://picasaweb.google.com/102463851712712911502/June202012?authuser=0&feat=directlink)

The jQuery page code is:

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page">
  <div data-role="content">
    <div id="selectview" style="width:50%; float:left">
      <label for="select-view1" style="font-size:12px" >First</label>
      <select name="select-view1" class="select-view" id="select-view1" >
        <option value="aaa">AAAAAAAAA</option>
        <option value="bbb">BBBBBBBB</option>
        <option value="ccc">CCCCCCCCC</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="select-function-div" style="width:50%; float:left">
      <label for="select-view2" style="font-size:12px" >Second</label>
      <select name="select-view2" id="select-view2"  >
        <option value="ddd">DDDDDDDDDDDDD</option>
        <option value="eee">EE</option>
        <option value="mafffin">FFFFFFFFFFFF</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think it the link should be fixed now, tx

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` from style tag like this

```
<div id="selectview" style="width:50%;">
      <label for="select-view1" style="font-size:12px" >First</label>
      <select name="select-view1" class="select-view" id="select-view1" >
        <option value="aaa">AAAAAAAAA</option>
        <option value="bbb">BBBBBBBB</option>
        <option value="ccc">CCCCCCCCC</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing semicolons after your style elements, which might be causing some display issues,
try:
style="width:50%; float:left;"
instead

Comment: Missing semicolons at the end of an inline style don't affect the style.